# \frenchspacing not setting the space factor codes correctly?

Tags: spacing, amsmath, frenchspacing

When I type `\showthe\frenchspacing`, I get the following output:

```
> \frenchspacing=macro:
->\sfcode `\.1006\sfcode `\?1005\sfcode `\!1004\sfcode `\:1003\sfcode `\;1002\sfcode `\,1001 .
```

Shouldn't all of those numbers be exactly 1000? I've also checked each of the space factor codes individually with `showthe\sfcode.` etc. and gotten the same incorrect values. When `\frenchspacing` is not in effect, the six space factor codes are exactly correct: 3000 for `.`, `?`, and `!`; 2000 for `:`; 1500 for `;`; and 1250 for `,`.

I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (MiKTeX 2.7) (preloaded format=latex 2010.12.14).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package `amsmath` loads the package `amsgen` which redefines `\frenchspacing` as:

```
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1006\sfcode`\?1005\sfcode`\!1004%
  \sfcode`\:1003\sfcode`\;1002\sfcode`\,1001 }
```

The reason is explained in the file [amsgen.dtx](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsgen.dtx):

> Change `\frenchspacing` to ensure that
>   `\@addpunct` will continue to work
>   properly even when ‘french’ spacing is
>   in effect.

You can see the effect of this redefinition in the following code (comment/uncomment the lines with `\def\frenchspacing` to see the difference):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@addpunct#1{\ifnum\spacefactor>\@m \else#1\fi}
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1006\sfcode`\?1005\sfcode`\!1004  \sfcode`\:1003\sfcode`\;1002\sfcode`\,1001 }
%\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode `\.\@m \sfcode `\?\@m \sfcode `\!\@m \sfcode `\:\@m \sfcode `\;\@m \sfcode `\,\@m}
\makeatother

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\frenchspacing}\par

\makeatletter
Title\@addpunct{.} Text\par
Title.\@addpunct{.} Text\par
Title,\@addpunct{.} Text\par
Title?\@addpunct{.} Text\par
Title!\@addpunct{.} Text\par
Title:\@addpunct{.} Text\par
Title;\@addpunct{.} Text\par
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The `\@addpunct` command only adds its argument if there wasn't a punctuation before it, which is useful to ensure that a punctuation is always present even if the user didn't provide it (in inline section titles, for example). This does not work if all the `\sfcodes` of the punctuation are equal to `1000` so `amsgen.sty` puts them to something bigger. The reason why the `\sfcodes` are all different instead of all equal to `1001` is to be able to differentiate between all the punctuation signs if needed.

Comment: @MSC: it's also worth remembering that the actual factor by which the space is multiplied is the spacefactor over 1000, so those changes are basically invisible.  I think there are a few examples in the TeXbook where the last digit is used for some purpose (like distinguishing punctuation) other than to produce space.

Comment: I am using `amsmath`, so it must be the cause. I figured that the space difference was virtually undetectable; I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a bug somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan: Knuth gives an example on p. 400 of the TeXbook: You can use penalties `-10001`, `-10002` and so on to communicate with the output routine.

Answer (score 3):

The original definition in latex.ltx is:

```
> \frenchspacing=macro:
->\sfcode `\.\@m \sfcode `\?\@m \sfcode `\!\@m \sfcode `\:\@m \sfcode `\;\@m \s
fcode `\,\@m .
l.6 \show\frenchspacing
```

As this minimal example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\show\frenchspacing
\end{document}
```

Without a minimal example from you it is impossible to say why it is different for you.