# Default spacing after periods

Tags: spacing, memoir

In LaTeX, what is the default space that is inserted after a period `.` inside a block of text?  What if I press `enter` (to start a new line in my GUI) after the period?

Is it any different in the `memoir` class?  Is there any way to change the default spacing?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

This is my text block.  I pressed spacebar twice before this sentence.

This is my text block. I pressed spacebar once before this sentence, but the spacing is the same.

This is my text block.
I pressed enter once before this sentence, and now the spacing is different.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Spaces are generally ignored by TeX, so it doesn't matter if you put one, two or even ten spaces after a sentence.  TeX standardly puts more than an single space after punctuation. You can turn this off using the `\frenchspacing` command:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\Huge
This is some text. This is some more text.

\frenchspacing
This is some text. This is some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

The space that TeX inserts is actually a stretchable space, and so the spacing between the punctuation mark and the following word will depend partially on the rest of the line. It doesn't depend on how you enter your source.  So in the example you post, you can make the spacing the same if the text is exactly the same:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\large
This is my text block.  I pressed spacebar twice before this sentence.

% This has one line in the source
This is my text block. I pressed spacebar once before this sentence, but the spacing is the same.

% This one has two lines in the source.
This is my text block.
I pressed spacebar once before this sentence, but the spacing is the same.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Notice that in this example the space after the `.` is different in the first sentence, since the first sentence contains "twice" and the other sentences in the examples contain "once".  This small difference is enough to affect the spacing.

Comment: I'm actually getting a different amount of spacing when I start a newline (by pressing `enter` once) in my GUI... please see my updated MWE.  Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/frenchspacing-not-setting-the-space-factor-codes-correctly) question has some good info on how spaces are set

Comment: @jamaicanworm, actually the space before the I in each of your three paragraphs is different, but this is because the words in the paragraphs are different, so tex stretches by different amounts while linebreaking. Try copying the text _exactly_ and just changing the white space from one or two spaces or a newline, you will see the white space has no effect.

Comment: @David Carlisle, you're exactly right!  Thank you so much for the clarification.