# Spacing issue in equation reference

Tags: spacing, hyperref

When I type
`(Eq.\ref{eq.15})`
The output is

[image]

Obviously the spacing between "Eq." and "1.15" is too closed.
But when I type (adding a space)
`(Eq. \ref{eq.15})`

The output is:

[image]

Obviously the spacing between "Eq." and "1.15" is too wide!

My question is how I can get appropriate spacing.

Comment: Some related questions: [Default spacing after periods](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42736) --- [When should I use intersentence spacing (\`\@')?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55112) --- [Why should I put a ~ before \ref or \cite?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9633) --- [When should I use non-breaking space?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15547) Edit: I guess the third one indirectly answers your question.

Comment: Please show us a complete, little document with the relevant settings. It's not standard that "Eq.\ref{eq.15}" produces (Eq.1.15).

Comment: Check out cleveref to standardize referencing.

Comment: Sorry, @Gonzalo Medina, I have add parenthesis to my code

Comment: `Eq.~\ref{eq.15}` is the correct input for two reasons: the space is not “end of sentence” and no line break can happen at that space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `cleveref`: you'll have less typing and the spacing will be fine. Demo:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq-1st}
  J = \frac{1}{2}(a - b)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq-2nd}
  K= \frac{1}{2}(a + b)
\end{equation}

I want to reference eq.\eqref{eq-1st}

I want to reference \cref{eq-1st}.

\Cref{eq-1st,eq-2nd} show that…

\end{document}
```

[image]