# How can I check if a header has an ending full stop?

Tags: conditionals, punctuation

I am modifiyng some macros to enforce a section style that should end with a full stop. The full stop is added automatically, but sometimes people add the full stop and I get two. How can I modify the code to detect the punctuation and add it only if it is needed? I guess I need to use futurelet, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: It would be helpful to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also clarify any ambiguities in your question.

Comment: @PeterGrill I am sorry the code was really long. Will give one in my next question.

Comment: Ok. But keep in mind, everyone's real code is really long. The point is to create a new document as small as possible that reproduces the problem. In this case you could just define a macro that adds punctuation and passes it two test cases: one with the punctuation, one without?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly it is always best to post a MWE. As you have not posted one I am posting a general answer, for exact formatting of the section you will need to add your own formatting commands.

You don't need a `\futurelet`. TeX keeps track of special codes for letters and punctuation to place the right amount of space after a stop. We can check the value of the `\spacefactor` macro and add a stop or do nothing if it is already there.

```
\newcommand\@addpunctuation[1]{\ifnum\spacefactor>1000\else#1\fi}
```

The rest of the code are minor details. Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@addpunctuation[1]{\ifnum\spacefactor>1000\else#1\fi}
\newcommand\buildhead[1]{#1\@addpunctuation.}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\addhead}[1]{\buildhead{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Section[1]{\addhead{#1}}
\def\section{\secdef \starcmd \unstarcmd}
\def\starcmd[#1]#2{\bfseries\Large\addhead{#2}}
\newcommand\unstarcmd[1]{\bfseries\setcounter{section}{O}\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section} \addhead{#1}}}
\makeatother
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\section[small title]{Testing}\\
\section{Testing}\\ % remains as is 
\Section{Testing}\\
\Section{Testing.}
\end{document}
```

If you want the macro to work both for `\frenchspacing` and `\nonfrenchspacing`, you can try:

```
\newcommand\@addpunctuation[1]{%
   \nonfrenchspacing
   \ifnum\sfcode`.=1000
     \ifnum\spacefactor>1000\else#1\fi
   \else
      \ifnum\spacefactor>1000\else#1\fi
      \nonfrenchspacing
  \fi
}
```

and test with

```
\frenchspacing

Test. \fbox{A test test}

\nonfrenchspacing

Test. \fbox{A test test}
```

You can also visit the link quoted by [Philippe Goutet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1973/philippe-goutet) in the comments below.

Comment: The last example entry has two dots if `\frenchspacing` is active.

Comment: @morbusg `\frenchspacing` sets all the `sfcodes` to 1000 so one would have to modify the above to check for `frenchspacing`. Perhaps a better technique is to check the value of the `sfcode` for the stop and then do the check.

Comment: @morbusg: see [\frenchspacing not setting the space factor codes correctly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10767) for how the ams solved the problem with its `\@addpunct` macro.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Thanks for the link. I posted an alternative in the answer which I had already worked out, would you please care to check it out and comment on it?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Using your `\@addpunctuation` macro with `\frenchspacing`, I get two dots. The problem with the idea of starting `\@addpunctuation` with `\nonfrenchspacing` is that the space factor has already been set, so it's too late as `\frenchspacing Text.\nonfrenchspacing\the\spacefactor` will show. I don't think you can get around redefining `\frenchspacing` as the AMS did.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet I agree: `\@addpunct` as in `amsmath` needs a redefinition of `\frenchspacing` that slightly increases the space factor of the punctuation symbols; this doesn't influence the typesetting (only by a few scaled points, actually), but allows for recognizing them.

Comment: yes `\spacefactor` is being tracked while the horizontal list is being build, so changing `\sfcode` settings afterwards has no effect. So if you want uniform spacing with identical `sfcodes` then your nice trick simply doesn't work.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Can you  please try my workaround at the bottom of the question? This seems to work. Of course will not work with AMS.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: your last code is what we were talking about and unfortunately doesn't work. I think the confusion comes from a typo: the last `\nonfrenchspacing` should be a `\frenchspacing` and so your macro switches the rest of the document to `\nonfrenchspacing` thus `\frenchspacing Text.\@addpunctuation{.} Text.\@addpunctuation{.}` will not work correctly the first time but will the second as `\frenchspacing` is no longer in effect.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Thanks I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be solved at a macro level without 'meddling' with the space factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{catoptions}
\robust@def*\newsection#1{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\currtitle{\cpttrimspaces{#1}}%
  \def\currlabel{}\def\lasttok{}%
  \xifinsetFT{\detokenize{\label}}{\cptoxdetok\currtitle}{}{%
    \def\reserved@a##1\label##2##3\cpt@nil{%
      \def\currtitle{##1##3}%
      \def\currlabel{\noexpand\label{##2}}%
    }%
    \expandafter\reserved@a\currtitle\cpt@nil
  }%
  \def\getlasttok##1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\@car##1\@nil\cpt@nnil
    \else
      \edef\lasttok{\unexpanded{##1}}%
      \expandafter\getlasttok
    \fi
  }%
  \expandafter\getlasttok\currtitle\cpt@nnil
  \s@expandarg\ifinsetTF\lasttok{\dots\ldots\textellipsis}{%
    \@tempswatrue
  }{%
    \begingroup
    \lccode`\X=133
    \lowercase{\endgroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \ifstrcmpTF\expandafter\@car\lasttok\@nil X}{%
      \@tempswatrue
    }{%
      \@tempswafalse\let\elt\relax
      \def\siso@do##1{%
        \xifinsetFT{\detokenize{##1}\elt}{\cptoxdetok\currtitle\elt}{}{%
          \@tempswatrue\loopbreak
        }%
      }%
      \siso@@loop{.!?:\dots\ldots\textellipsis}%
    }%
  }%
  \def\elt{\expandcsonce\currtitle}%
  \cptexpandarg{\endgroup\section}{\if@tempswa\elt\else\elt.\fi\currlabel}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newsection{Test section.\label{sec:1}}
As seen later in Section~\ref{sec:this} \ldots.
\newsection{Test section}
\newsection{Test section.}
\newsection{Is this a test section?}
\newsection{Heh, this is test section!}
\newsection{Test section\dots}
\newsection{Test section\ldots}
\newsection{Test section\textellipsis}
\newsection{Test section\label{sec:this}\ldots}
As seen earlier in Section~\ref{sec:1} \ldots.

% I have accounted for the ASCII character 133 but you may not get it to print:
\newsection{Test section …}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will not work with `\dots`: `\newsection{Test section\dots}` will give four dots instead of three

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: Please do you have other failure modes, so that I can try to address them at once?

Comment: Well, it should work with all the punctuation so it is safer to also add `,` and `:` and `;` but that should be all. Of course, the solution should also work with `\ldots`, `\textellipsis ` or other `\dots` variants as well as the symbol `…` (in unicode, U+2026).

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: I haven't seen section and paragraph headings ending with comma (,) or semicolon (;). So I think we should leave them out.

Comment: Well, for inline sections, you could imagine things like `\paragraph{Start of the title,} end of the title.` (I've done this myself a few times). Anyway, as a comma or a semi-colon should never be followed by a full stop, just as well add them, it's safer. You never know what can cross the mind of your end users.